# Get an error: missing authentication using hapi-auth-jwt2

Tags: node.js, jwt, hapi

this my routes code

```
const Joi = require('joi')
const handler = require('../handler/get-request')

const route = {
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/IB',
  options: {
    tags: ['api', 'IB', 'request'],
    description: 'Request New User IB',
    notes: 'It will return new user IB data',
    validate: {
      payload: {
        data: Joi.object().keys({
          cifNo: Joi.string().min(5).max(45).required(),
          userId: Joi.string().min(5).max(45).required(),
          deviceInfo: Joi.string().min(3).max(45).required()
        })
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      'hapi-swagger': {
        responses: {
          '200': {
            description: 'Success'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    auth: 'ib'
  },
  handler
}

module.exports = route
```

and this is my code where i registered the plugin hapi-auth-jwt

```
await server.register(require('hapi-auth-jwt2'))

    server.auth.strategy('ib', 'jwt', {
      key: config.internalServiceAccessToken,
      validate: async function (decoded, request) {
        // See https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-auth-jwt2
        // provides checking for invalidated token after user logout
        request.auth.decoded = decoded
        const user = await request.server.methods.services.ib.auth.findUser(decoded.username)
        
        return { isValid: user, credentials: decoded }
      },
      verifyOptions: { algorithms: ['RS256'] }
    })
```

when i hit my routes, i got this error message, "Error: Missing Authentication".

Can someone explain me why? and help me to fix this error. Big Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with hapi but are you sure that you are sending the token to client, storing it and then sending it back so the your backend can verify it?

Comment: @MatusDubrava now i got an error 'invalid token' when i throw the jwt token into my headers of my routes. could you give me a solution? thanks btw for ur attention